# How to hide element based on input value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide/show input and div based on Input value.

The code below isn't working:

HTML:

```
<div>
     <span class='just-show'>Show This Label</span>
     <input class='for-input' type='text' value='*$set-by-sql-data*'>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".for-input").val()=='') {
        $(".just-show").show();
        $(".for-input").hide();
    } else {
        $(".just-show").hide();
        $(".for-input").show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

How to hide the element without event (ex: click) ? Just on ready function.

Comment: since you are setting the input value ahead of time, why not just hard-code the other fork? you know how the IF will execute since the input value is set by you onready() and not by the user...

Comment: If you are doing both show and hide perhaps a toggle may be better. It will automatically show/hide

Comment: You're right Mr. dandavis. But, Input value insert by client side and set default 'NULL'. So, data is possible to empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  // Does some stuff and logs the event to the console
});
```

Or

```
$("input").change(function(){
    // Does some stuff and logs the event to the console
});
```

Where `input` is Input identifier like your `.for-input`

**Your desire Jquery code:**

```
$(document).on('change', '.for-input', function() {
    if ($(".for-input").val()=='') {
        $(".just-show").show();
        $(".for-input").hide();
    } else {
        $(".just-show").hide();
        $(".for-input").show();
    }
});
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".for-input").val()=='') {
        $(".just-show").show();
        $(".for-input").hide();
    } else {
        $(".just-show").hide();
        $(".for-input").show();
    }
    //return false;
  
  $(document).on('change', '.for-input', function() {
     if ($(".for-input").val()=='') {
        $(".just-show").show();
        $(".for-input").hide();
    } else {
        $(".just-show").hide();
        $(".for-input").show();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <span class='just-show'>Show This Label</span>
     <input class='for-input' type='text' value='*$set-by-sql-data*'>
</div>
```

Comment: OP asked "_How to hide the element without event_", at least tell him that's impossible...

Comment: Cool! This is work. now I'm realize I forgot about jquery lib. I'm Thank Sir.

Comment: Is $(document).ready(function () {}) only cannot handle? Mr dandavis

Comment: It impossible to hide element without event @ Roger Schimidt

Comment: I apply your source to selected mode on select tag. But always show nothing. Can you help me solve this? Thank Mr. Uttam Kumar Roy

Comment: If your input field is empty then it will hide@Roger Schimdt

Answer (score 0):

You can set the css property to display none.

```
$('.for-input').css('display', 'none');
```